# Let $X =\{n^3 + 3n^2 +3n | n>0\}$ and $Y = \{ n^3 -1 | n>0\}.$ Prove that $X =Y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, derivatives

Let $X=\{n^3+3n^2+3n\mid n>0\},$ and $Y=\{n^3-1\mid n>0 \}$. Prove that $X=Y$.

I tried proving it by adding some values to $X$ and $Y$, but I could not make it equal.

Comment: Try $$n=1$$, then your Statement is false.

Comment: Observe that $n^3+3n^3+3n=n^3+3n^3+3n+1-1=(n+1)^3-1\;$ . Check you did copy correctly the statemnet of hte problem.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting

Comment: X = { n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n | n is greater than or equal to zero. Y = { n^3 - 1| n>0} prove that X = Y

Comment: in X {n is greater than or equal to zero}

Comment: I don't think "derivatives" is a good tag for this post

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  Presumably $n$ ranges over the natural numbers.  $Y$ includes $0$ from $n=1$ while $X$ does not.  Otherwise the sets are equal because the expression for $X$ is $(n+1)^3-1$, so every element that is in $X$ will be in $Y$.  It is made harder to see by the fact that $n$ is used to define both $X$ and $Y$, but it is only a dummy variable.  Make the definition $Y=\{m^3-1|m\gt 0\}$ and you can say the element of $X$ that is caused by $n$ is also an element of $Y$ that is caused by $m=n+1$.

The statement would be true if the definition of $X$ were changed to include $n \ge 0$

Comment: X={ n^3+3n^2+3n | n≥0}  and Y={n^3−1|n>0}. Prove that X=Y.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  Any element of $X$ is also in $Y$ and vice versa.  It is easier to say if you use $m$ for the definition of $Y$.

Comment: So final answer proves X =Y? Will that be satisfied?

Comment: That is right.  Have you just calculated the first few elements of each set?